# Macro that clears duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro that loops through rows F and G, clearing a range if it finds a duplicate F&G combo.

Right now, if it finds a unique combo (say, F(1) G(2)), it will delete all of those combos.

How can I change this macro to purge every time it clears, so that it is only clearing duplicates directly below the original?

Thanks.

```
Sub clearDupsA()
    
        Dim lngMyRow As Long
        Dim lngMyCol As Long
        Dim lngLastRow As Long
        Dim objMyUniqueData As Object
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        lngLastRow = Range("F:G").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
        
        Set objMyUniqueData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        For lngMyRow = 1 To lngLastRow
            If objMyUniqueData.exists(CStr(Cells(lngMyRow, 6) & Cells(lngMyRow, 7))) = False Then
                objMyUniqueData.Add CStr(Cells(lngMyRow, 6) & Cells(lngMyRow, 7)), Cells(lngMyRow, 6) & Cells(lngMyRow, 7)
            Else
                Range(Cells(lngMyRow, 6), Cells(lngMyRow, 7)).ClearContents
            End If
        
        Next lngMyRow
        
        Set objMyUniqueData = Nothing
        
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ErrorHandler:
       
        Exit Sub
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use a dictionary.  Just use a variable that gets replaced each time a different combination is found.

Comment: Did you try [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates)?

Answer (score 1):

do not use a dictionary.  Instead just use a variable that gets replaced when a new combo is found:

```
Sub clearDupsA()
    
    Dim lngMyRow As Long
    Dim lngMyCol As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim tempHolder As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With ActiveSheet 'Don't let vba determine the sheet
        lngLastRow = Range("F:G").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
        For lngMyRow = 1 To lngLastRow
            If tempHolder <> (CStr(.Cells(lngMyRow, 6) & .Cells(lngMyRow, 7))) Then
                tempHolder = (CStr(.Cells(lngMyRow, 6) & .Cells(lngMyRow, 7)))
            Else
                .Range(.Cells(lngMyRow, 6), .Cells(lngMyRow, 7)).ClearContents
            End If
        
        Next lngMyRow
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clear Consecutive Duplicates

[image]

```vb
Sub clearDupsA()
    
    Const FirstRowAddress As String = "F2:G2"
    Const Delimiter As String = "|!|"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(FirstRowAddress)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim OldString As String
    Dim NewString As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        NewString = CStr(Data(r, 1)) & Delimiter & CStr(Data(r, 2))
        If StrComp(NewString, OldString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Data(r, 1) = Empty
            Data(r, 2) = Empty
        Else
            OldString = NewString
        End If
    Next r
    
    rg.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```